# "There are no property pages for the selection" error in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide

When I go to edit a properties page in Visual Studio 2015 with C++, I'm always getting the error, "There are no property pages for the selection."  This usually happens when I'm switching from one Platform to another (e.g. x64 -> Win32).

Usually it will work if I switch the platform from the main window, but if I try to switch it in the Property Pages, I always get that error.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is a bug that has been in Visual Studio since forever. Through experimentation I have discovered that you only hit this bug if you open the project properties by going to the `Project` menu and selecting `<ProjectName> Properties...`. Instead, if you open the `Solution Explorer` toolbar, and then right-click on the project and select `Properties` from the context menu, you will not hit this issue.

Comment: Thank you!  It worked, I just wish I knew why it suddenly started acting like this in the first place.

Comment: For who else had this same problem and this answer didn't work. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548857/project-properties-dont-open-there-are-no-property-pages-for-the-selection).

Comment: Worked for me with VS Community 2017 v15.7.3. Thanks!

Comment: Just right-click the project, press `Unload Project`, then `Reload Project` and it started working for me.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo question worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I solved the issue by closing all Visual studio windows and open the solution again(I had two Visual studio open for two separate solutions).

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be linked between MSBuild tools and environment paths. On visual studio 2017 v15, after I had downloaded MSBuild tools it updated the VCTarget path to

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

where it should actually point to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

In my case changing the environment path wasn't working and eventually I had to manually update the VCTargets path from regedit: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions`

also make sure the priority of path you define in environment variable is correct.