# Where exactly is macro $(VCTargetsPath) defined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

We had a discussion before.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e04e7791-c0c4-4598-b900-310878f5af45/how-can-i-locate-and-change-the-vctargetspath-variable?forum=msbuild

After hours searching .props files, all the $(VCTargetsPath) in .prop and .targets are deleted, but Visual Studio can still recognize this macro/variable correctly.

By modifing Microsoft.Cpp.ToolsetLocation.props, $(VCTargetsPath) can be modified and in consequence VS can no longer create new project.

So, where exactly this macro defined?

I believed that this macro is not and shouldn't be hardcoded.

Comment: "I believed that this macro is and shouldn't be hardcoded." <-- That sentence makes *no* sense.

Comment: What is your main goal of your issue so far? Did you want to find such property or change it to use other path?

Comment: My main golal is that after deleting all definitions in .prop and .target, $(VCTargetsPath)  still exists and I want to know the reason, sorry for my late reply. @Perry Qian-MSFT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where exactly is macro $(VCTargetsPath) defined?

**Actually**, `VCTargetsPath` property is defined in the MSBuild system `props` or `targets` files under **MSBuild** folder(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild`). And the files are nested and related to each other. **Therefore**, the values of various properties are referred to each other in the level-by-level files, and the value of `VCTargetsPath` is no exception.

==========================================================================

**MSBuild** is actually equivalent to soft coding. Once **MSBuild** is installed, it exists as a bunch of dlls and various established `props` and `targets` files. You can modify its properties or extend its functions in various ways in the `props` or `targets` file. The MSBuild itself is an [open source build tool](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild). **It is not as unchangeable as you think.**

==========================================================================

The `VCTargetsPath` is actually defined in the msbuild props file called `Microsoft.Cpp.ToolsetLocation.props` as you said.

[image]

It's just that the various `targets` and `props` files in **MSBuild** are nested and interrelated. `VCTargetsPath` is set as the value of `_VCTargetsPathForToolset` property while `_VCTargetsPathForToolset` is defined in another associated `targets` or `props` file.

**In general**, use `<import projects="xxxx\xxx.props or targets" />` to embed another file in the current `targets` or `props` file.

**And** there are so many files in **MSBuild** that if you want to search layer by layer until you find the final specific value, it might seem a little complicated.

**Besides**, `VCTargetsPath` is the path of some tools used by **MSBuild** to compile c++ projects.

The default value in **VS2019** is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160`.

You can write a custom target in the `xxx.vcxproj` file to output its value.

**1)** write this in `xxx.vcxproj` file:

```
<Target Name="test123" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="$(VCTargetsPath)"></Message>
</Target>
```

**2)** Then rebuild your project and you can see this:

[image]

**It** is the **MSBuild** system defined path. If you change it easily, it will cause the project to fail to compile, unless you have a set of **self-defined system** similar to MSBuild to build C++ projects, and then put it in new path, let the new path overwrite `VCTargetsPath` property.

**In addition**, I am curious why you want to find the lowest `VCTargetPath` value. If you want to know the principle of it, the above answer explains it.

**And** if you want to overwrite its value, you can just create an **environment system variable** called `VCTargetsPath` directly, and then set its value to a new one.

**Restart** VS to enable such new value. It is much easier than modifying the `targets` file.

Comment: Thanks. But still qustion: deleted all definitions, VS still can recognize it doesn't make sense. This is my operation procedure: https://shrib.com/#SportiveLemur-WAyQ4K         try it in VMWare and you will find it unresonable.

Comment: The `VCTargetsPath` are defined under these files and actually, when Microsoft creates MSBuild, it already has a mechanism to prevent `VCTargetsPath` from being empty. And it is encapsulated in other inaccessible path, and the default value is the system value.But for overriding its value, you can directly modify it in the `Microsoft.Cpp.ToolsetLocation.props` file.

Comment: That helps! And btw, is that from source code or from your colleague in MSFT?  @Perry Qian-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

**VCTargetsPath** looks rather a variable than a macro to me. However, it is defined in **msbuild.exe.config**, and can, depending on your installation of msbuild, be found in (for example):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\
```

Or search on disk for msbuild.exe.config. I use [this tool](https://www.voidtools.com/) for searching.
Many instances of this config file may be present on disk but pick the one that is most plausible for your build environment.